# Copying and identities

Tags: file, copy, dns

We have deployed a solution which periodically needs to copy a file from one server (Server A) to a shared folder on another server (Server B). Server A is in a domain and and Server B isn't. The copying will take place in a process running as a Windows service.

My issue is how to do this the best way with regards to the share on Server B and which identity to use. We don't want to use the Everyone "account". It would be great if we didn't have to use impersonation on the Windows service.

Since Server B isn't aware of any users in the domain we created a local user on Server B with the same username and password as the domain account that the service is running as. That seems to work but is that the correct procedure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have the service run as an account that is named the same thing and has the same password on Server B.